# Boot Mac Virtual Machine into Recovery Mode Using Windows Keyboard

Tags: mac, virtual-machine

I have a Mac OS X virtual machine running on my Windows 10 Dell laptop. Now I want to boot the Mac VM into the recovery mode, it's expected to press and hold <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> key combination at the boot time. But I just have a Windows keyboard, there is no either <kbd>Command</kbd> or <kbd>Option</kbd> key. So I use the <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> keys together but it doesn't work. Please help me get into recovery mode! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not going to happen, you have no recovery partition, nor any Apple boot ROM to act upon the Cmd/R combination even if you had a Mac keyboard.